# Is there any alternative to "truncate" which sounds safer?

Tags: c#, file-io

I have an application that reads a linked list<sup>1</sup> from a file when it starts, and write it back to the file when it ends. I choose `truncate` as the file mode when writing back. However, `truncate` sounds a little bit dangerous to me as it clears the whole content first. Thus if something goes wrong, I cannot get my old stuff back. Is there any better alternative?

<sub>1: I use a linked list because the order of items may change. Thus I later use `truncate` to update the whole file.</sub>

---

The right answer reputation goes to Hans as he first pointed out `File.Replace()`, though it is not available for Silverlight for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is covered well by the .NET framework.  Use the [File.Replace()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.replace.aspx) method.  It securely replaces the content of your original file with the content of another file, leaving the original in tact if there's any problem with the file system.  It is a better mouse trap than the upvoted answers, they'll fail when there's a pending delete on the original file.

There's an overload that lets you control whether the original file is preserved as a backup file.  It is best if you let the function create the backup, it significantly increases the odds that the function will succeed when another process has a lock on your file, the most typical failure mode.  They'll get to keep the lock on the backup file.  The method also works best when you create the intermediate file on the same drive as the original so you'll want to avoid GetTempFileName().  A good way to generate a filename is Guid.NewGuid().ToString().

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot understand whether I should create the backup?

Comment: No, you don't create the backup file, the method does.  Just pass a name for it, typical is "filename.ext.bak".

Answer (score 5):

Write to a new temporary file. When finished and satisfied with the result, delete the old file and rename/copy the new temporary file into the original file's location. This way, should anything go wrong, you are not losing data.

As pointed out in Hans Passants answer, you should use [`File.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.replace.aspx) for maximum robustness when replacing the original file.

Comment: +1 for temp file.  The only window for fail is if the deletion is done but the rename did not complete.  Even this unlikely scenario can be covered by checking for a temp file if the app starts up and finds no 'main' file.

Comment: No, this fails with data loss when the file is opened for delete sharing.  By far the most common reason, virus scanners and search indexers do that.

Answer (score 2):

The "best" alternative for robustness would be to do the following:

1. Create a *new* file for the data you're persisting to disk
2. Write the data out to the new file
3. Perform any necessary data verification
4. Delete the original file
5. Move the *new* file to the original file location

You can use [`System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettempfilename.aspx) to provide you with a uniquely named temporary file to use for step 1.

Comment: Same problem as driis' answer.

Answer (score 2):

You have thought to use `truncate`, so I assume your input data is always anew, therefore....

1. try ... catch to rename your original file to something like 'originalname_day_month_year.bak'
2. Write ex-novo your file with new data.

In this way you don't have to worry to loose anything and, as a side effect, you have a backup copy of your previous data. If that backup is not needed, you can always delete the backup file.